# Lista de listas que segue a ordem dos elementos de uma sequência

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Então, estou tentando fazer um "*Jogo da paciência*" em Python, porém com números maiores do que os de uma baralho convencional.

Pra isso, eu forneço uma sequência/lista de elementos os quais quero ordenar em "pilhas", no entanto não tá dando muito certo as formas que eu estou fazendo... O método que eu tenho que utilizar é o de lista de listas e com isso eu fiz o seguinte código até agora:

```
s = list(map(int,input("\n⌨ Forneça os elementos da sequência: ").split(',')))

l = len(s)

pilha     = [[] for i in range(0,l)]
pilha[0] += [s[0]] # Aqui eu adiciono o primeiro termo da sequência (como se fosse a primeira carta)

i = 0
x = s[i]
y = s[i+1]

for i in range(0,l):
    for elemento in s:
        if (x > y) and (elemento == y):
            pilha[i] += [elemento]

        elif (x <= y) and (elemento == y):
                i += 1
                pilha[i+1].append(elemento)

print('\nCriam-se então as seguintes pilhas: ')
    
for p in range(0,l):
    if pilha[p] != []:
        print('\nPilha[%d]: %s' %(p,pilha[p]))
```

Minha ideia basicamente foi pegar o os elementos adjacentes da sequência, por exemplo, se **s=[14, 8, 7, 17, 20]**, eu pego direto o segundo elemento s[1] == 8 e adiciono na pilha[0]. No entanto, eu imaginava que o comando for avaliasse todos os i's no intervalo (0,l), porém isso não acontece, e quando eu tento colocar um contador em i, ocorre um erro de indexação, dizendo "invalid syntax: pilha[i+1].append(elemento)". Tentei usar pilha[i+1] += [elemento] e também não funcionou com contador... Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria muitíssimo grato :)

Quando dou run nesses comandos acima, obtenho o resultado:

Pilha[0] = [14, 8]

Pilha[1] = [8]

Pilha[2] = [8]

Pilha[3] = [8]

Pilha[4] = [8]

Pilha[5] = [8]

E o resultado correto seria:

Pilha[0] = [14, 8, 7]

Pilha[1] = [17, 11]

Pilha[2] = [20]

Estou usando **Python 3.8**

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar um contador para definir a pilha atual. Se o elemento for menor é adicionado, se não for cria-se uma pilha nova e aumenta-se o contador.

O primeiro elemento é logo adicionado e o ciclo começa no segundo elemento.

```
s = list(map(int,input("\n⌨ Forneça os elementos da sequência: ").split(',')))

l = len(s)

pilhas = []

x = s[0]
pilha = 0

pilhas.append([x])

for i in range(1, l):
    if s[i] < x:
        pilhas[pilha].append(s[i])
    else:
        pilha += 1
        pilhas.append([s[i]])
    x = s[i]

print(pilhas)
```